# how to retrieve JSON request into method using rest java?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-2.0

i am using simple java and jersey for rest. below is method. from postman i am sending json request and want to retrieve this data into method without declaring POJO class. but unable to retrieve.

```
@Path("{entity}/markLabel")
@PUT
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response markLabel() 
        throws Exception {
}
```

i want to retrieve request json parameter(fileType,groupId,sourceId) into method  [this request json parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hslaU.jpg).

[this is header part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8BFK.jpg)

can someone help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to retrieve the request parameters or headers in another method?

One method handles one request, thats the way, but if you want to isolate some part of the functionality into seperate method you can call the other method inside the request handling method.

```
@Path("{entity}/markLabel")
@PUT
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response markLabel(ReqObject String reqBody) throws Exception {
      //////do something
         someOtherMethod(reqBody);
      //////do something
}




class ReqObject{
     String fileType;
     String groupId;
     String sourceId;
   //getters and setters
}
```

Comment: i am using jersey. in jersey there is no @RequestBody

Comment: then in that case i guess you just to need to remove the @RequestBody annotation and run your application or you can map it to an object with the request body keys as properties and map the request to that type check the modified ans.

Comment: i think u have not read my question. i want request param without creating POJO class. well, i am able to get param in string form.